# Ways to get child functions

Tags: powershell

If I have a main function in a parent directly not in my profile.
For this example lets say Xfunction.ps1 is inside C:\main. Meaning C:\main\Xfunction.ps1

Inside that function I want to call other related child functions.

I know I can use `Import-Module` but what I am curious about is how can I search for the child functions reasonably?
My issue with `Import-Module` is that there is no intelligence to it. Either the child is at the location or error.

I have considered making some kind of searcher that will look for child functions like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory "$ChildFun" -File -path 'c:\' -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1
```

Is there a better way or best practice I am not aware of?

Comment: You could package your `Xfunctions.ps1` as a module and supply the function names in the module manifest - that way you can do `Get-Command Child-Function` even if the module hasn't yet been loaded

Comment: I have thought about this a lot and besides your idea and mine with the search I am not aware of a better means. is there a environment variable that tells me where the script is running ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen make your reply an answer so we can close this.